# Do I need to dispose/close XDocument.Load(string)?

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-xml

I can't find any info about whether or not I should dispose/close this object after using it... Here is the msdn link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343181.aspx

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No, you don't  - it doesn't even implement `IDisposable`.  The `XDocument` and `XElement` classes use `XmlReader` under the covers and handle the disposing of the underlying reader for you.

Answer (score 8):

Easiest way to find out is to look if it implements IDisposable

Comment: And, the easiest way to do that is with 'Go To Definition', 'Object Browser' or Reflector

Comment: Sure, that's a good/simple way to do this... I really couldn't find a dispose of close method, so I'm under the assumption that like Andrew said, this is really handled by the XDocument class it self. Thanks for your quick answer.